# how can i add a scrollbar to a big image

Tags: support, images

Take this question for example:

[Moodle does not load label modules from datebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20683251/moodle-does-not-load-label-modules-from-datebase)

How can the big image at the bottom be resized to full hight and width in addition to a horizontal scrollbar?

At the moment this image is unreadable if not rightclicked -> show graphic

I did not find any solution for this on meta

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ItpeR.pnghttp://i.stack.imgur.com/ItpeR.png ?

Comment: No offense, but I think that any time you need an image so big it needs scrollbars, you should at least step back and ask if you *really* need that image. The image you're concerned with would be just fine as text, IMO.

Comment: I consider the preview/linked-image approach superior to scrollbars. You can instantly see what the image is about and if you need a bigger version, you can simply click it. Auto-Linking would be cool, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to *resize* the image in the editor.

You could resize it in an image editor before adding it to the website. Also, you get a preview of what your post will look like if you are not sure how it will come out.

Now if that really isn't an option, I suggest you simply upload your image and post a link in your question.